# Getting multiple timestamp logs in python

Tags: python, logging, timestamp

Newbie in python here.

I'm trying to generate timestamps of each user's login using python but I can't seem to append to a stack in a csv file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here's my complete code: https://github.com/zarexalvindaria/dataStruc/blob/master/login_v3

Comment: Please provide a [mre], since a link 1) will loose any value to future visitors once the code is fixed and 2) can become invalid. Also, can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help. See: [ask] and [edit] your post to include required details.

Comment: You are opening in `"w"` mode - this will overwrite - for logfiles `"a"` (append) is normally more appropriate https://github.com/zarexalvindaria/dataStruc/blob/df14fb80a517bc6ace8fb4311e3d83764eb84676/login_v3#L108

Comment: Sorry about this,  Богдан. I'll provide these details on my next questions. Thank you for taking a look on this.

@alaniwi, that solved my problem at first but later on, I decided to use the csv function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change three lines of your code to get it working.
Replace this section alone.

```
if password1 in verify:
#Adds the timestamp to csv file
    log_count += 1
    log_in_save = []
    #userlog = username1 + "_log_in_save.csv"
    userlog = "Log_in_save.csv"
    user_time_in = username1 + " login " + str(log_count) + " " + str(time_in)
    log_in_save.append(user_time_in)
    login_timestamp = open(userlog, "a")
    login_timestamp.write(str(log_in_save) + "\n")
    login_timestamp.close()
    login_sucess() # confirms login success
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Vignesh. I was able to find a csv function which solved my problem. I moved away from stacks since it's not doable in this case--at least in my current skill in python.

```
def append_list_as_row(file_name, list_of_elem):
    # Open file in append mode
    with open(file_name, 'a+', newline='') as write_obj:
        # Create a writer object from csv module
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        # Add contents of list as last row in the csv file
        csv_writer.writerow(list_of_elem)

append_list_as_row(userlogin,log_ins)
```